# Unable to set custom colors inside ExpandableListView

Tags: android-layout, android

I'm an Android newbie.

I'm trying to set custom colors inside an ExpandableListView adapter. I have defined my colors in colors.xml, but I'm unable to use them in my adapter. I get an error "The method getResources() is undefined for the type ExpandableListAdapter"

The function expects an int. I've tried to pass my result from getResources in, but, it does'nt work. I've also tried to pass in a hex value, but it does'nt change anything.

How can I use my custom colors in my code?

```
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean arg1, View convertView,
        ViewGroup arg3) {
    int n = 0;
    String laptopName = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_item, null);
    }
    TextView item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.demo);
    item.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    item.setText(laptopName);

    convertView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple));

    return convertView;
}
```

Thanks guys, the following snippet works

```
this.context = (Activity) context;
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(this.context.getResources().getColor(R.color.purple));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a context instance somewhere in the adapter instead of this

```
convertView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple));
```

it should be this

```
convertView.setBackgroundColor((your context).getResources().getColor(R.color.purple));
```

and if you don't have a reference to the context just pass it in to the adapter constructor

Answer (score 1):

As loulou8284 mentioned you can put it in your XML, or if it is fixed, define it with `Color.rgb()`, but to make your code running you need to get the reference to your Context as your class is not declared inside a context-class:

```
convertView.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.purple));
```

Comment: Won't work. I get: an error "The method getContext() is undefined for the type ExpandableListAdapter"

Comment: Its because you can't call that method in an adapter

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the color in you .xml file ( in your item xml file )

Answer (score 0):

Use `setBackgroundResource()` rather than `setBackgroundColor()`

setBackgroundResource() takes an integer resource index as parameter, and load whatever resource that index points to (for example; a drawable, a string or in your case a color).

setBackgroundColor(), however takes an integer representing a color. That is, not a color-resource, but a direct, hexadecimal, rgba value (0xAARRGGBB).